# If you were asked to evaluate $x^2$ for $x = -1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

Would you bracket the $x$? I ask this because $-1^2$ is equal to $-1$, but $(-1)^2$ is equal to $1$. Which is valid?

Comment: Yes bracket the $x$!!

Comment: Yes, bracket the $x$. The symbol $x^2$ means $x\cdot x$ which in our case is $(-1)(-1)=(-1)^2$.

Comment: $-1^2$ means you're really going to square $1$, but then you're gonna go and make the answer negative. Compare with $(-1)^2$, which means that you're going to square the whole thing inside the parenthesis, that is, you're squaring $-1$, and you're not going to change any signs afterwards. Evaluating $x^2$ at $x=-1$ clearly means you want to square the whole thing (that is $-1$), so yeah bracket the $x$.

Comment: Definitely brackets. In hand-written notation $-1^2=-1$, but in some programming languages, the unary $-$ has precedence over multiplication and other operations, so this even varies with software you use! Read this chapter:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Exceptions_to_the_standard

Comment: To take a more-elaborate example, consider $x=a+b+c$. Certainly, you wouldn't write $x^2$ as $a+b+c^2$, which applies the squaring operation to a *portion* of $x$. Rather, you'd write $(a+b+c)^2$. The parentheses form a protective bubble, indicating that $a+b+c$ should be treated as a *unit*, and that the squaring operation applies to that unit: *I'm squaring (this stuff here).* Likewise, when $x=-1$, you write $x^2=(-1)^2$ to make perfectly clear to everyone that *I'm squaring (negative $1$)*.

Comment: It's also worthwhile to note that protective bubbles are implicitly everywhere; for instance, you *could* write $x^2$ as $(x)^2$ (or even $(x)^{(2)}$). Then, when $x=a+b+c$ or $x=-1$, you simply substitute into the bubble: $(a+b+c)^2$ or $(-1)^2$. Computer programming "macros" and "#define" formulas often make liberal use of such pre-emptive protective bubbling.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you need to bracket the $x$, so the result is $(-1)^2=1$. When you substitute a variable for its value in an equation you always need brackets around it. However sometimes those brackets are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=-1$, then it $x$ has the value of $-1$, so squaring this value will give you $(-1)^2$.

What you did in $x^2\to-1^2$ instead is not assuming the value of a variable, it's replacing a character representing the variable with a string representing a number and then reinterpreting the expression. Of course, this expression doesn't have to have the same meaning.